# In PowerBI,how to split a column when using DirectQuery?

Tags: powerbi

When Using direct query, powerBI is saying that splitting a column is not supported. I have a column and I need to split it into many columns. Do I need to use the import data option or is there a workaround. I am not able to use the import option because my table is very very huge.

Comment: What is the Direct Query source?

Comment: It is an Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported through direct query. Direct query method has a lot of limitations when it comes to manipulation of the source dataset like you cannot create calculated columns or measures, number formatting etc. With Direct query you basically see the source as it is with very little modification possibilities.